# PostgreSQL Error: Relation already exists

Tags: postgresql, identifier, create-table

I am trying to create a table that was dropped previously.

But when I do the `CREATE TABLE A ..`. I am getting below error:

> Relation 'A' already exists.

I verified doing `SELECT * FROM A`, but then I got another error:

> Relation 'A' does not exists.

I already tried to find it in `\dS+` listing all relations, and it is not there.
To complicate this, I have tested this by creating this table in another database and I got the same error. I am thinking that could be an error when this table was dropped. Any ideas?

Here is the code: I'm using a generated code from Power SQL. I have the same error without using the sequence. It just works when I change the name and in this case I can not do that.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE csd_relationship_csd_relationship_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE csd_relationship (
    csd_relationship_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('csd_relationship_csd_relationship_id_seq'::regclass),  
    type_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    object_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT csd_relationship PRIMARY KEY (csd_relationship_id)
);
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE 'A'` and `SELECT * FROM 'A'` are syntax errors.  PostgreSQL uses double quotes for identifiers.

Comment: Sorry. I didnt used single quotes. It was a bad example, I was trying to simplify my question. I will transcribe the code exactly.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I finally discover the error. The problem is that the primary key constraint name is equal the table name. I don know how postgres represents constraints, but I think the error "Relation already exists" was being triggered during the creation of the primary key constraint because the table was already declared. But because of this error, the table wasnt created at the end.

Comment: The proper solution is to use a `serial` column like I provided in my answer.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  Foreign key constraint names are shared across the entire pg database, so by copy-pasting some commands I ended up trying to create a fk constraint with the same name as one created previously (for another table), which threw the same "Relation ___ already exists" error and led me here... +1 :)

Comment: could you add a brief code example of the correctly renamed stuff/syntax

Comment: oh I see CONSTRAINT csd_relationship PRIMARY KEY (csd_relationship_id), same name as CREATE TABLE csd_relationship

Comment: Emphasizing @glyph's answer. This would seem to be a sneaky, if understandable feature of pg.

Answer (score 18):

There should be no single quotes here <strike>`'A'`</strike>. Single quotes are for string literals: `'some value'`.
Either use double quotes to preserve the upper case spelling of "A":

```
CREATE TABLE "A" ...
```

Or don't use quotes at all:

```
CREATE TABLE A ...
```

... which is identical to:

```
CREATE TABLE a ...
```

... because all unquoted **identifiers** are [folded to lower case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in Postgres. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

---

You can avoid problems with the index name completely by using simpler syntax:

```sql
CREATE TABLE csd_relationship (
  csd_relationship_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, type_id             integer NOT NULL
, object_id           integer NOT NULL
);
```

Does the same as your original query, only it avoids naming conflicts by picking the next free identifier automatically. More about the [`serial` type in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

Comment: Sorry i didnt actually used single quotes. It was a bad example.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot create a table with a name that is identical to an existing table or view in the cluster.  To modify an existing table, use [`ALTER TABLE` (link)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-alter.html), or to drop all data currently in the table and create an empty table with the desired schema, issue `DROP TABLE` before `CREATE TABLE`.

It could be that the sequence you are creating is the culprit.  In PostgreSQL, sequences are implemented as a table with a particular set of columns.  If you already have the sequence defined, you should probably skip creating it.  Unfortunately, there's no equivalent in `CREATE SEQUENCE` to the `IF NOT EXISTS` construct available in `CREATE TABLE`.  By the looks of it, you might be creating your schema unconditionally, anyways, so it's reasonable to use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS csd_relationship;
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS csd_relationship_csd_relationship_id_seq;
```

before the rest of your schema update;  In case it isn't obvious, **This will delete all of the data in the `csd_relationship` table, if there is any**

Comment: As I said, this table was already droped. When i do: DROP TABLE csd_relationship; 
ERROR:  table "csd_relationship" does not exist

Comment: It is not the sequence. I tried to create the table without creating the sequence and I got the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Another reason why you might get errors like "relation already exists" is if the `DROP` command did not execute correctly.

One reason this can happen is if there are other sessions connected to the database which you need to close first.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had a sequence with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it wasn't until I PAUSEd the batch file and scrolled up a bit, that wasn't the only error I had gotten. My `DROP` command had become `ï»¿DROP` and so the table wasn't dropping in the first place (thus the relation did indeed still exist). The `ï»¿` I've learned is called a Byte Order Mark (BOM). Opening this in Notepad++, re-save the SQL file with Encoding set to UTM-8 without BOM and it runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

You may be running the `CREATE TABLE` after already running it.  So you may be creating a table for a second time, while the first attempt already created it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was migrating from 9.5 to 9.6.
So to restore a database, I was doing :

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d databse -f dump.sql
```

Of course it was executing on the old postgreSQL database where there are datas! If your new instance is on port 5433, the correct way is :

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d databse -f dump.sql -p 5433
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this kind of error happens when you create tables with different database users and try to `SELECT` with a different user.
You can grant all privileges using below query.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO username;
```

And also you can grant access for DML statements

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO username;
```

Comment: for me it was just that i was using a different user by mistake, but wow that was weird. glad you posted this

Answer (score 0):

- The problem is that the primary key constraint name is equal the table name.
- I don't know how postgres represents constraints, but I think the error “Relation
  already exists” was being triggered during the creation of the primary key
  constraint because the table was already declared. But because of this error,
  the table wasnt created at the end.
- give different name to constrain

  **Note- go to SQL tab and check table name and constrain**

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You already found that the root of the problem was that the primary key had the same name as the table, but let me explain *why* that is a problem.

All primary and unique constraints are implemented using unique indexes. In PostgreSQL, that index must have the same name as the constraint. So your command tries to create an index named `csd_relationship`, just like the table.

Now in PostgreSQL, tables, indexes, sequences, views and composite data types all share the same *name space*, that is, there cannot be two of them with the same name in the same schema. The technical reason is that the metadata of all these objects are stored in the catalog table `pg_class`, and `pg_class` has a unique constraint on `(relname, relnamespace)`, that is, the combination of table name and schema.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error after running the terminal command "dotnet ef database update". My solution was to open the database and delete/drop tables with the same name.

Answer (score -1):

my error is :

```
cteate table xr_inbound_req(.......
   CONSTRAINT table_name PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

when change to this:

```
cteate table xr_inbound_req(.......
   CONSTRAINT pk_table_name PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

is ok
add `pk_` to prefix

Comment: `cteate table` seems wrong