# Access a specific schema in a PostgreSQL database via PHP

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database `userdb` with 5 schemas.

```
Schema 1- Persons
Schema 2- Project
Schema 3- Shop
Schema 4- Test
```

I was able to connect to the database using `pg_connect`. How do I access a specific schema in that database?

I was able to connect to a schema when there was only one in the database. But now since I have multiple schemas I am having difficulty in accessing any specific one.

```
 <?php
 // attempt a connection
 $dbh = pg_connect("host=**.****.*******.*** dbname=test user=merlin port=5433 password=passw123");
 if (!$dbh) {
     die("Error in connection test: " . pg_last_error());
 } 
// execute query
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM test.country";
 $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
 if (!$result) {
     die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
 }       

 // iterate over result set
 // print each row
 while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "Country code: " . $row[0] . "<br />";
     echo "Country name: " . $row[1] . "<p />";
 }       

 // free memory
 pg_free_result($result);       

 // close connection
 pg_close($dbh);      
?>
```

Comment: What is the difficulty you are having?

Comment: it gives me this error: `Error in SQL query: ERROR: relation "aircraft" does not exist at character 15.`

Aircraft is a table in one of my schemas.

Comment: Is the name of the table `aircraft` or `"Aircraft"`? More about mixed case identifiers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792912/postgresql-error-relation-already-exists/8793441#8793441

Answer (score 6):

Qualify the table with the schema name

```
select *
from my_schema.aircraft
```

Comment: I am getting this error - `Error in SQL query: ERROR: schema "aircraft" does not exist at character 15`

Answer (score 3):

Schema-qualify the table name as [Clodoaldo already advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110205/939860). Or set the **[`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)** for a permanent effect. It works much like a search path in the file system.

*How* permanent depends on how you set it. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

Comment: @Clodoaldo 's method doesnt seem to work for some reason. my php code. And ive only just begun SQL n PHP so I dint understand you procedure. I am editing my question to incorporate my code now.

Answer (score 3):

use:
SET search_path TO myschema;  or

SET search_path TO myschema, myschemab;

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-schemas.html