# Pass multiple values in single parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, plpgsql

I want to call a function by passing multiple values on single parameter, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jobTitle('270,378');
```

Here is my function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(int)
RETURNS TABLE (job_id int, job_reference int, job_job_title text
                                            , job_status text) AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
select jobs.id,jobs.reference, jobs.job_title,
       ltrim(substring(jobs.status,3,char_length(jobs.status))) as status
FROM jobs ,company c
WHERE jobs."DeleteFlag" = '0'
and c.id= jobs.id and c.DeleteFlag = '0' and c.active = '1' 
and (jobs.id = $1 or -1 = $1)
order by jobs.job_title;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can someone help with the syntax? Or even provide sample code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `VARIADIC`

Like [@mu provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19203004/939860), [`VARIADIC`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) is your friend. One more important detail:

You **can also** call a function using a `VARIADIC` parameter with an array type directly. Add the key word `VARIADIC` in the function call:

```
SELECT * FROM  f_test(VARIADIC '{1, 2, 3}'::int[]);
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM  f_test(1, 2, 3);
```

#### Other advice

In Postgres 9.1 or later [`right()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) with a *negative* length is faster and simpler to trim leading characters from a string:

```
right(j.status, -2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
substring(j.status, 3, char_length(jobs.status))
```

You have `j."DeleteFlag"` as well as `j.DeleteFlag` (without double quotes) in your query. This is probably incorrect. See:

- [PostgreSQL Error: Relation already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792912/postgresql-error-relation-already-exists/8793441#8793441)

`"DeleteFlag" = '0'` indicates another problem. Unlike other RDBMS, Postgres properly supports the [**`boolean`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) data type. If the flag holds `boolean` data (`true` / `false` / `NULL`) use the `boolean` type. A [character type like `text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) would be inappropriate / inefficient.

#### Proper function

You don't need PL/pgSQL here. You *can* use a simpler SQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test(VARIADIC int[])
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, reference int, job_title text, status text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   SELECT j.id, j.reference, j.job_title
        , ltrim(right(j.status, -2)) AS status
   FROM   company c
   JOIN   job     j USING (id)
   WHERE  c.active
   AND    NOT c.delete_flag
   AND    NOT j.delete_flag
   AND   (j.id = ANY($1) OR '{-1}'::int[] = $1)
   ORDER  BY j.job_title
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=37204d71299e95f3a829947b6fb8a926)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9b5e2/1)</sub>

Comment: Thanks I got it @Erwin Brandstetter

Answer (score 5):

Don't do strange and horrible things like converting a list of integers to a CSV string, this:

```
jobTitle('270,378')
```

is not what you want. You want to say things like this:

```
jobTitle(270, 378)
jobTitle(array[270, 378])
```

If you're going to be calling `jobTitle` by hand then a [variadic function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) would probably be easiest to work with:

```
create or replace function jobTitle(variadic int[])
returns table (...) as $$
    -- $1 will be an array if integers in here so UNNEST, IN, ANY, ... as needed
```

Then you can `jobTitle(6)`, `jobTitle(6, 11)`, `jobTitle(6, 11, 23, 42)`, ... as needed.

If you're going to be building the `jobTitle` arguments in SQL then the explicit-array version  would probably be easier to work with:

```
create or replace function jobTitle(int[])
returns table (...) as $$
    -- $1 will be an array if integers in here so UNNEST, IN, ANY, ... as needed
```

Then you could `jobTitle(array[6])`, `jobTitle(array[6, 11])`, ... as needed and you could use all the usual [array operators and functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) to build argument lists for `jobTitle`.

I'll leave the function's internals as an exercise for the reader.