# VARIADIC parameter must be the last input parameter

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

How to create two `VARIADIC` parameters. Look at my code and correct me.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ip_source_test(
  text, text, date, date, VARIADIC int[], VARIADIC text[]
)
RETURNS TABLE (no_documents int, "Report By" text, "Report_By" text) 
AS $$
BEGIN
  IF 'Source Member' = $1 THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT.....
  ELSEIF 'company' = $1 THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT.....
  ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'Not Worked';
  END IF;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Error: VARIADIC parameter must be the last input parameter.
```

In SQL code im supposed to use 6 parameters. Please update me with sample code.

Comment: How are you expecting to call this function? Can you give an example?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I am not sure but My Exception is something like this 

`select * from ip_source_test('Source Member','week','2012-09-01','2013-09-01',VARIADIC '{128,270}'::int[],VARIADIC '{AJ,alexandra}'::text[])`

Comment: This is a follow-up to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter

Comment: Logically, there could only be one variadic parameter, since it refers to an unknown number of additional arguments. You would invoke the function as `ip_source_test(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)`, where `a` through `d` are the first four arguments, and the rest are gathered up in the last variadic parameter. To expect the function to know how the remaining six arguments are to be distributed is beyond its psychic powers.

Answer (score 1):

There can be only one `VARIADIC` per function, since variadic encompasses **all** the other arguments passed by the caller.

If you mean for the caller to use arrays, there's no point in using variadic anyway, the function signature could look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ip_source_test(text,text,date,date,int[], text[])
```

Comment: `VARIADIC` does not encompass *all* other arguments. There can be other parameters before that one.

Comment: By _other_ arguments I mean the ones beyond those specified in the function declaration. My understanding is that both our answers are saying exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you:

> VARIADIC parameter must be the last input parameter.

It follows logically that a function can only take a **single `VARIADIC` parameter**. There can be other (non-`VARIADIC`) parameters *before* that one. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)

> Effectively, all the actual arguments at or beyond the `VARIADIC`
> position are gathered up into a one-dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  VARIADIC parameter must be the last input parameter

Because I didn't use the `VARIADIC` parameter `nums` as the last parameter as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(VARIADIC nums INTEGER[], num INTEGER)
RETURNS VOID         -- ↑ Here ↑
AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, I used the `VARIADIC` parameter `nums` as the last parameter as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(num INTEGER, VARIADIC nums INTEGER[])
RETURNS VOID                      -- ↑ Here ↑
AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) says below:

> The function is declared by marking the last parameter as VARIADIC;