# Passing multiple values in single parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql

Let's say I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(character varaying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
some_integer integer;
begin
   Select column2 from test_table where column1 in ($1) into some_integer;
end;
Return some_integer;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
Select * from test_function ('data1', 'data2','data3');
```

Of course, it cannot be done this way, because Postgres tries to find function with this name and three parameter which doesn't exists.

I tried to put quotes around commas but in that case parameter is interpreted wrong:  **data1', 'data2','data3**, like one string.

Is there a way to put multiple values in parameter so IN clause can recognized it?

Comment: I think you can pass an array parameter. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570393/postgres-integer-arrays-as-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Your function wouldn't be created. `RETURN` after `END` is syntactical nonsense.)

A function with a [**`VARIADIC`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) parameter does *exactly* what you ask for:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(date, date, VARIADIC varchar[])
  RETURNS SETOF integer
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT col1
FROM   test_table
WHERE  col3 > $1
AND    col4 < $2
AND    col2 = ANY($3)
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9b61c9565812dad12f0a498fd0c52950)* - demo with additional parameters
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7b150/4)</sub>

Call (as desired):

```
SELECT * FROM test_function('data1', 'data2', 'data3');
```

Using a simple SQL function, plpgsql is not required for the simple example. But `VARIADIC` works for plpgsql functions, too.

Using `RETURNS SETOF integer` since this can obviously return multiple rows.

Details:

- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)
- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function)
- [VARIADIC parameter must be the last input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275206/variadic-parameter-must-be-the-last-input-parameter/19276503#19276503)
- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/select-rows-such-that-names-match-elements-of-input-array-for-pgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

Comment: but what if i have more parameters?
let's say (date, date, VARIADIC varchar[])... how do I call this function?

Comment: when I call it like this:
SELECT * FROM test_function('2015-01-01','2015-01-20','data1', 'data2','data3');
I get error - function test_function(date, date, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @AcoVujic: You can only have *one* `VARIADIC` parameter and it must be the last one. Please read the manual, I added a link. Your call would work. I added a fiddle.