# Function to select column values by comparing against comma separated list

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, parameter-passing

I want to compare my comma delimited string with column values.

I did the following, which is not returning the expected result. `ll = '"Java,CPP"'` is coming dynamically.

```
create or replace function testing(ll text)
returns void as
$body$
Declare

       foo text[];
       ko text[];
BEGIN
       select unique_code into foo from codings
       where  unique_code = ANY (regexp_split_to_array(ll, '\,'));
       raise info '%',foo;
END;
$body$
Language plpgsql;
```

I got below error

> ```
> ERROR:  column "Java,CPP" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT "Java,CPP"
>                ^
> QUERY:  SELECT "Java,CPP"
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function testing() line 8 at assignment
> ```

The value of `ll` is coming dynamically like above and now it is return NULL also in the row I have 'Java' and 'Cpp', both values in matching case.

```
select unique_code from codings;

unique_code
  Java
  Python
  CPP
  C
  Haskell
```

I also tried trim but not work. The updated code is here:

```
create or replace function testing(ll text)
returns void as
$body$
Declare

       foo text[];
       --ll text;
       ko text[];
       oo text;
BEGIN
      --oo := replace(ll,'"','');
      raise info '%',regexp_split_to_array(trim(both '"' from ll), '\,');
      ko := regexp_split_to_array(trim(both '"' from ll), '\,');

       ---ll := "CH-PREP,CH-PRMB";
       --select(regexp_split_to_array(ll, '\|')) into ko;
        --foo := array(select unique_key from membership_map);
       select  unique_code into foo from codings where  unique_code = ANY(ko);
       raise info '%',foo;
       --raise info '%', ko;
END;
$body$
Language plpgsql;
```

Then:

`select testing('"Java,CPP"');`

> ```
> ERROR: malformed array literal: "Java"
> DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information
> CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function testing(text) line 16 at SQL statement
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`TRIM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) to strip the `"` from your `ll` value:

```
select unique_code 
from codings 
where unique_code = ANY (regexp_split_to_array(trim(both '"' from '"Java,CPP"'), '\,'));
```

Output for your sample data:

```
unique_code
Java
CPP
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b5609/1)

You also have an issue in that you are assigning multiple values in one statement, for which you need to use the `ARRAY` operator. Change

```
select unique_code into foo from codings where unique_code = ANY(ko);
```

to

```
select array(select unique_code from codings where unique_code = ANY(ko)) into foo;
```

Comment: Now I got the error 
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "Java"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function testing(text) line 16 at SQL statement

Comment: raise info '%',regexp_split_to_array(trim(both '"' from ll), '\,');
      ko := regexp_split_to_array(trim(both '"' from ll), '\,');
      
       ---ll := "CH-PREP,CH-PRMB";
       --select(regexp_split_to_array(ll, '\|')) into ko;
        --foo := array(select unique_key from membership_map);
       select unique_key into foo from membership_map where  unique_key = ANY(ko);

Comment: Please update your question with this updated code. It's too hard to read in a comment.

Comment: I think you need to change `select  unique_code into foo from codings where  unique_code = ANY(ko)` to `select array(select  unique_code  from codings where  unique_code = ANY(ko)) into foo;`

Comment: Now it is working thank you Please make it updated post to accept it.

Comment: @RJD I have updated my answer with this change. I was unable to do it earlier as it has been night time...

Answer (score 1):

You got the first error:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "Java,CPP" does not exist
> ```

... for missing **single quotes** around your string literal in the ***function call***. Like

```
SELECT testing("Java,CPP");  -- missing ''!
```

You probably want to trim those double quotes from the input, so the call should really be:

```
SELECT testing('Java,CPP');
```

Related:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

With the *call* fixed, the lurking error from a **data type mismatch** in the function body strikes. You try to assign `unique_code text` to `foo text[]`:

> ```
> ERROR: malformed array literal: "Java"
> ```

For example, this would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(_ll text[])  -- taking array of text
  RETURNS text[] AS
$func$
DECLARE
   foo text[];
BEGIN
   foo := ARRAY(  -- array constructor
      SELECT unique_code 
      FROM   codings
      WHERE  unique_code = ANY(_ll)
      );

   RETURN foo;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT testing('{Java,CPP}');  -- note syntax of array literal
```

See:

- [Pass array literal to PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138792/pass-array-literal-to-postgresql-function/17139751#17139751)

Passing a **valid array literal** also avoids the expensive and unnecessary `regexp_split_to_array()` call. (Regexp functions are powerful but comparatively expensive.)

**Or** the same as **`VARIADIC`** function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(VARIADIC _ll text[])
...  -- rest as above
```

You can still pass array literals (or true array values) with the keyword `VARIADIC` in the call:

```
SELECT testing(VARIADIC '{Java,CPP}'); -- with array
```

Or you can pass a list of element values (up to 100):

```
SELECT testing('Java','CPP');          -- with list of values
```

Related:

- [Passing multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109037/passing-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/28115702#28115702)
- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)
- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

---

**If** you absolutely must pass your string in the **original form**, `trim()` the double quotes and use the much cheaper `string_to_array()` instead of `regexp_split_to_array()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(_ll text)
  RETURNS text[] AS
$func$
DECLARE
   foo text[];
BEGIN
   foo := ARRAY(
      SELECT unique_code 
      FROM   codings
      WHERE  unique_code = ANY(string_to_array(trim(_ll, '"'), ','))
      );

   RETURN foo;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT testing('"Java,CPP"'); -- even with enclosing double quotes
```

Aside: rather don't use a cryptic `ll` as parameter name. Easily misread as `11` ...