# How can a PostgreSQL function accept an integer or array of integers for the same function?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, types, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

I have a function in Postgres 9.6 that accepts an `int[]` parameter. I'd like to have the function accept a single int as well (and convert it to a single element array if necessary).

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_subordinates(inp_persona_ids integer[])
 -- Get all subordnates of the people passed in as array
 -- TODO allow a single persona ID (int) to be passed in as inp_persona_ids
 RETURNS TABLE (persona_id int) AS
 $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY(
            WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
                -- passed in persona_id
                SELECT
                    id AS persona_id,
                    manager_id
                FROM
                    personas
                WHERE
                    id = ANY(inp_persona_ids)
                UNION
                -- and all subordinates
                SELECT
                    p.id AS persona_id,
                    p.manager_id
                FROM
                    personas p
                    JOIN children c ON p.manager_id = c.persona_id
            )
            SELECT 
                children.persona_id
            FROM
                children
            LEFT JOIN
                personas on children.persona_id = personas.id
            WHERE personas.disabled IS NOT TRUE
        );
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

How would I change the function definition and also add some conditional logic to test for `int` and change to `ARRAY[int]` if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to handle this in a single function, but you can just overload the function with an `integer` parameter and pass this as an array to your existing function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_subordinates(inp_persona_id integer)
RETURNS TABLE (persona_id int) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM get_subordinates(ARRAY[inp_persona_id]);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Perhaps you might also want to check the argument(s) against `NULL`, this is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

It ***is*** possible with a single function using the **`VARIADIC`** modifier:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_subordinates(VARIADIC inp_persona_ids int[])
  RETURNS TABLE (persona_id int) AS
$func$
WITH RECURSIVE children AS (   -- passed in persona_id
   SELECT id AS persona_id, manager_id, disabled
   FROM   personas
   WHERE  id = ANY(inp_persona_ids)

   UNION ALL   -- and all subordinates
   SELECT p.id AS persona_id
        , p.manager_id
   FROM   children c
   JOIN   personas p ON p.manager_id = c.persona_id
)
SELECT c.persona_id
FROM   children c
WHERE  c.disabled IS NOT TRUE
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

**But** you need to add the keyword `VARIADIC` in the call when providing an array instead of a list:

```
SELECT * FROM  get_subordinates(VARIADIC '{1,2,3}'::int[]);
SELECT * FROM  get_subordinates(1,2,3);
SELECT * FROM  get_subordinates(1);
```

If that's not an option you are back to function overloading as suggested in another answer.

See:

- [Passing multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109037/passing-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/28115702#28115702)
- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)

#### Asides

- Looks like this can be a simpler SQL function.
- `UNION` made no sense. Duplicates can only occur if your tree goes in circles, which would create an endless loop and the rCTE would error out. Use the cheaper `UNION ALL`.
- `LEFT JOIN` made no sense. The added `WHERE` forced it to behave like a plain `[INNER] JOIN` anyway.
- But remove the join completely and retrieve the column `disabled` inside the rCTE.

Comment: Expecting the upstream caller to use variadic for arrays won't work, so the overloading is the solution here. The simplification in your example helps with readability and performance. Appreciate that.