# Alternative ways to extract the contents of a JSON string

Tags: json, postgresql

Consider the following query:

```
select '"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"'::json;
```

This will return a single record of a single element containing a JSON `string`. See:

```
test=# select json_typeof('"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"'::json);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   json_typeof 
-------------
 string
(1 row)
```

It is possible to extract the contents of the string as follows:

```
=# select ('"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"'::json) #>>'{}';
     json      
---------------
 {"foo":"bar"}
(1 row)
```

From this point onward, the result can be cast as a JSON `object`:

```
test=# select json_typeof((('"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"'::json) #>>'{}')::json);
 json_typeof 
-------------
 object
(1 row)
```

This way seems magical.

I define no path within the extraction operator, yet what is returned is not what I passed. This seems like passing no index to an array accessor, and getting an element back.

I worry that I will confuse the next maintainer to look at this logic.

Is there a less magical way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Is it that you have a column of type json and you want it rendered as text, eg  `{"foo":"bar"}`?

Comment: @Bohemian I was trying to simplify this down as much as I could. The practical use-case here is that I have a `json` column that mistakenly contains json _strings_ which contain quoted json objects, rather than _just_ json objects. My example above is the same: a json object encapsulated by a json string.

I can extract using the above operator, but I could see it being really confusing. This is less of a "I'm stuck" question, and more of a "help me find a better way" question.

Comment: Also, this might be a question for the postgres mailing list. I can float it there.

Comment: Why don't you store `'{"foo":"bar"}'` directly storing a JSON key/value pair as an escaped JSON string doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

But you *did* define a path. Defining "root" as path is just another path. And that's just what the [`#>>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) is for:

> Extracts JSON sub-object at the specified path as `text`.

Rendering as `text` effectively *applies* the escape characters in the string. When casting back to `json` the special meaning of double-quotes (not escaped any more) kicks in. Nothing magic there. No better way to do it.

If you expect it to be confusing to the afterlife, add comments explaining what you are doing there.

**Maybe**, in the spirit of clarity, you might use the equivalent function `json_extract_path_text()` instead. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

> Extracts JSON sub-object at the specified path as text. (This is functionally equivalent to the `#>>` operator.)

Now, the function has a `VARIADIC` parameter, and you typically enter path elements one-by-one, like the example in the manual demonstrates:

> ```
> json_extract_path_text('{"f2":{"f3":1},"f4":{"f5":99,"f6":"foo"}}',
> 'f4', 'f6') → foo
> ```

You cannot enter the "root" path this way. But (what the manual does not add at this point) you can alternatively provide an actual array after adding the keyword `VARIADIC`. See:

- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)

So this does the trick:

```sql
SELECT json_extract_path_text('"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"'::json, VARIADIC '{}')::json;
```

And since we are all about being explicit, use the verbose SQL standard cast syntax:

```sql
SELECT cast(json_extract_path_text('"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"'::json, VARIADIC '{}') AS json)
```

Any clearer, yet? (I would personally prefer your shorter original, but I may be biased, being a "native speaker" of Postgres..)

The question is, why do you have that odd JSON literal including escapes as JSON string in the first place?

Comment: "(The question is, why do you have that odd JSON literal including escapes as JSON string in the first place?)"

It was data mistakenly written as text from the application code. :grimacing: The query I was writing was to clean up the data.

Comment: @EdCarrel: I see. The remaining question then: Is this question answered properly?