# Creating index results in "relation already exists" error

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I had a table and I deleted it manually.

Now when I am trying to create it one more time, I am getting next error:

> Error: pq: relation "some_table_pkey" already exists

How I can delete this relation?

Next cases don't work:

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS some_table_pkey;

DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS some_table_pkey;
```

P.S. Please don't recommend drop database and restore from dump.

Comment: Indexes, constraints, views and tables share the same namespace in Postgres. You might have another index, view, constraint or table with that name in your database.

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT oid, relname, relnamespace::regnamespace, relkind FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'some_table_pkey';`?

Comment: "Don't work" is not an adequate description.  Read the error message.  If you don't understand it, show it to us and ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a primary key with the same table name, try creating a table with serial as the primary key.

CREATE TABLE some_table (
some_table_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
col1 integer NOT NULL,
col2 integer NOT NULL
);

refer:[PostgreSQL Error: Relation already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792912/postgresql-error-relation-already-exists)