# Script does not create tables but pgAdmin does

Tags: postgresql

I am running a script that creates a database, some tables with foreign keys and insert some data, but somehow creating the tables is not working, although it doesn't throw any error: I go to pgAdmin, look for the tables created and there's no one...

When I copy the text of my script and execute it into the Query Tool, it works fine and creates the tables.

Can you please explain me what I am doing wrong?

Script:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test01 WITH (FORCE); --drops even if in use

CREATE DATABASE test01
    WITH
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'German_Germany.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'German_Germany.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    IS_TEMPLATE = False
    ;

CREATE TABLE customers
(
   customer_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE contacts
(
   contact_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   customer_id INT,
   contact_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   phone VARCHAR(15),
   email VARCHAR(100),
   PRIMARY KEY(contact_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer
      FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) 
      REFERENCES customers(customer_id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE 
);

INSERT INTO customers(customer_name)
VALUES('BlueBird Inc'),
      ('Dolphin LLC');     
   
INSERT INTO contacts(customer_id, contact_name, phone, email)
VALUES(1,'John Doe','(408)-111-1234','john.doe@bluebird.dev'),
      (1,'Jane Doe','(408)-111-1235','jane.doe@bluebird.dev'),
      (2,'David Wright','(408)-222-1234','david.wright@dolphin.dev');
```

I am calling the script from a Windows console like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -f "C:\Users\my user name\Desktop\db_create.sql" postgres
```

My script is edited in Notepad++ and saved with Encoding set to UTF-8 without BOM, as per a suggestion found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34728446/7586301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using `-U postgres` command line parameter, and also using database name as last parameter (`postgres`).

So all your SQL commands was executed while you are connected to `postgres` database. Of course, `CREATE DATABASE` command did creation of `test01` database, but `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` did executed not for `test01` database, but for `postgres` database, and all your tables are in `postgres` database, but not in `test01`.

You need to split your SQL script into 2 scripts (files): first for 'CREATE DATABASE', second for the rest of.

You need to execute first script as before, like

```
psql.exe -U postgres -f "db_create_1.sql" postgres
```

And for second one need to choose the database which was created at 1st step, like

```
psql.exe -U postgres -f "db_create_2.sql" test01
```

Comment: thanks! that solved my problem, but.... isnt possible to run it in one step? I tried creating the database with an alias like `CREATE DATABASE test01 AS db` and then trying to refer to this alias when refering to the tables, but didn't work... I guess i could create a `perl` script to implement calling the two files...

Comment: @PaulEfford You can add a `\connect test01;` after your `CREATE DATABASE test01...` statement. It's `psql` interpreting the script so it'll recognise the [meta-command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) and switch to the newly created db.

Comment: @Zegarek that definitively helped me to achive creating a db and its tables from within a single script, thanks! 